# Why not the inverse of inverse function of a standard normal distribution calculation at scipy.stats python identical?

Tags: python-3.x, scipy

I tested the following example

```
from scipy.stats import norm
i=0.2
k=0.5
i==norm.cdf(norm.ppf(norm.cdf(norm.ppf(i)+k))-k)
```

The result gives `False`

If I check the value of `norm.cdf(norm.ppf(norm.cdf(norm.ppf(i)+k))-k)`, it is `0.19999999999999996`.

Why does this happen? Is there a better way to run the inverse of an inverse function?

Comment: When doing numerical calculations with floating point numbers, there is always roundoff error. One wouldn't expect exact equality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because they are numerical *approximations*. Just like `sqrt(2) * sqrt(2)` is not 2. There is just *no* floating point number such that  it's square (in floating point precision) is exactly 2.

Check out Goldberg's classic [What every computer scientist should know about floating point](https://www.itu.dk/~sestoft/bachelor/IEEE754_article.pdf), ACM Computing Surveys 23:1 (mar 1991), pp. 5-48.